# Django models ForeignKey return IDs

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I have been trying to search forums to get an answer for this, but it seems like its a bit tricky to search.

I have the following model which is pulling users from django User table:

```
class trendingidea(models.Model):
        iname = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=15)
        idea = models.TextField(unique=True)
        submittedon = models.DateTimeField()
        support = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
        readbyadmin = models.BooleanField()
        feasibilitycheck = models.BooleanField()
        submittedby = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="submitted_by")
        assignedto = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name="assignedto")
```

However when i query the database and pull the information:

**`ti=list(trendingidea.objects.values())`**

**`print(ti)`**

```
[{'readbyadmin': False, 'id': 1, 'idea': 'cisco', 'feasibilitycheck': True, 'submittedby_id': 1, 'support': 1, 'submittedon': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 6, 11, 8, 10, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'iname': 'cisoc', 'assignedto_id': 1}]
```

in place of `submittedby` and `assignedto` it gives me `submittedby_id`: 1 and `assignedto_id`: 1.

I wanted the usernames and not their IDs.
is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, by referring to the related field with the `__` prefix. The only downside is that you have to list all the other fields as well:

```
trendingidea.objects.values('readbyadmin',
                            'id',
                            'idea',
                            'submittedon',
                            'support',
                            'readbyadmin',
                            'feasibilitycheck',
                            'submittedby__name',
                            'assignedto__name')
```

Note that your dictionary will have `submittedby__name` and `assignedto__name` keys.